# Java/Android get array from xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a list of longitude and longitude points in an xml file that is used throughout my application. I find my self repeating this code to get points often and think there must be a better way?

```
    String[] mTempArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stations);
    int len = mTempArray.length;
    mStationArray = new ArrayList<Station>();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        Station s = new Station();
        String[] fields = mTempArray[i].split("[\t ]");
        s.setValuesFromArray(fields);
        Log.i("ADD STATION", ""+s);
        mStationArray.add(s);
    }
```

XML is in the format of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="stations">
        <item>
            <name>Station name</name>
            <longitude>1111111</longitude>
            <latitude>11111</latitude>
            <code>1</code>
        </item>
```

And another (possible) problem is that to get just one station I have to get all of them and pull the one I want from the array. Is this going to be considerably slower? Can I make this array consistent throughout the app? (But keeping the separate Intent methodology)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same thought as [MilkJug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691706/java-android-get-array-from-xml/4691823#4691823), to use a utility method to create the stations, but I want to offer a slightly different approach: Move as much of the construction logic as possible into the `Station` class constructor. To keep the example simple, I'm moving the utility method into the `Station` class as well.

This provides an overall cleaner design, as outside of the Station class itself, your code should never have to deal with a Station object whose construction/initialization steps haven't been fully completed.

([kgiannakakis's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691706/java-android-get-array-from-xml/4691852#4691852) suggestion to use a database may be a better way to go if you have a lot of Station objects.)

```
public class Station {
    private static List<Station> sStationArray = null;

    /**
     * Construct a Station from a specially-encoded String. The String
     * must have all the necessary values for the Station, separated by tabs.
     */ 
    public Station(String fieldString) {
        String[] fields = fieldString.split("[\t ]");

        // For safety, setValuesFromArray() should be declared 'final'.
        // Better yet, you could just move its body into this constructor.
        setValuesFromArray(fields);

        // I'm assuming 'mName' is the name field for the Station
        Log.i("Station", this.mName);
    }

    public static Station getStationArray(Context ctx) {
        if (sStationArray == null) {

            // (Please don't use the prefix 'm' for non-member variables!)
            final String[] tempArray = 
                ctx.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stations);
            final int len = tempArray.length;

            // Passing the length into the ArrayList constructor (if it's
            // known, or can be guessed at) can be a very simple yet
            // effective optimization. In this case the performance boost
            // will almost certainly **not** be meaningful, but it's
            // helpful to be aware of it.
            sStationArray = new ArrayList<Station>(len);    

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                Station s = new Station(tempArray[i]);
                sStationArray.add(s);
            }
        }
        return sStationArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Would it matter if I changed it to an ArrayList?

Comment: It's already an ArrayList -- see the line `sStationArray = new ArrayList<Station>(len);`. You could change `sStationArray` to be of type `ArrayList<Station>`, but that would not make any difference in functionality or performance.

Answer (score 4):

Why not create a utility method that takes a context as a parameter and returns the station resources? For example:

```
public class StatUtil {
   private static List<Station> mStationArray = null;

   public static Station getStation(Context ctx) {
    if (mStationArray == null) {
      String[] mTempArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stations);
      int len = mTempArray.length;
      mStationArray = new ArrayList<Station>();
      for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        Station s = new Station();
        String[] fields = mTempArray[i].split("[\t ]");
        s.setValuesFromArray(fields);
        Log.i("ADD STATION", ""+s);
        mStationArray.add(s);
      }
    }

    return mStationArray;
  }
}
```

and call it from your code with:

```
stationArray = StatUtil.getStation(this);
```

Repeatedly fetching the stations will be slower than caching them, but not significantly slower unless you are fetching them in a loop. Doing as above will prevent multiple copies from being fetched.

Comment: The call to `getResources()` needs to be prefixed with `ctx.`

Answer (score 2):

I could propose two solutions:

1. You could create a Singleton class that initializes once, reads the data from the XML and stores the stations  in a List or a Map. Use a Map if you want to quickly find a station based on its name. The Singleton class will provide methods for retrieving all stations or just one of them.
2. Create a database table and store the information there. You may need more code, but the advantage will be that you will be able to run more advanced queries.